# Dismiss a view and present a new one from within applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app that presents it's own passcode entry when the user either launches the app or reopens it from the background. When the user opens it from the background there should be no 'flash' of the real app, in other words the security screen needs to be fully loaded before the user reopens the app.

I have this setup fine for the majority of screens.

In one scenario it's possible for the user to rotate the app which calls a segue from the tab bar controller to a horizontal view controller. In that instance I'm having some problems. If I don't pop the rotated screen then the input screen comes up horizontally, even though the user reopens the app in portrait..

If I do dismiss it with animation then the lock screen doesn't start to load until the app restarts, so you get a flash of content.

If I dismiss it without animation then the lock screen still comes up horizontally.

Here's what's called from `applicationDidEnterBackground`:

```
    TabBarController *tbc = (TabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;        

    void (^openPasscode)() = ^void() {
        KVPasscodeViewController *passcodeController = [[KVPasscodeViewController alloc] init];
        passcodeController.delegate = self;
        UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passcodeController];

        // Change animated to YES and the new view isn't loaded until after the app restarts
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];

    };

    if (tbc.isShowingLandscapeView) {
        [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:openPasscode];
    } else {
        openPasscode();
    }
```

Comment: Wonder if issuing a `[CATransaction flush]` after presenting your passcode screen in `applicationWillEnterBackground:` would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to subclass The UINavigationController that hold the passcode view controller and implements these methods (from UIViewController.h):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES; // when app launched while device in landscape. it needs to rotate to portrait.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == interfaceOrientation);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this, but must have missed a method or made a mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility...since `applicationDidEnterBackground` gets called on the main thread, anything you do with your views in there won't be visible until the next time through the main run loop (which doesn't happen until the app returns to the foreground - that's why you see your main screen flash up before the security view appears over top of it).

After you rearrange your views, what if you force the application to spin through the main run loop one more time before you leave.  You could try adding this before the end of `applicationDidEnterBackground`:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This is just a guess - I haven't tried it, but I'm hoping it will give you another direction to explore.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you present your passcode view in `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead of `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

My thinking is that when the application resumes, it will present your lock screen view controller before the main application screen appears - this would avoid any "flash" of the main view, and any changes in rotation would already be worked out before the view appears.

Comment: I had already tried this, apologies for not mentioning in the question.